# Multi-cluster writes to Delta Lake Storage in S3

Tags: python, databricks, delta-lake

Trying out

https://delta.io/blog/2022-05-18-multi-cluster-writes-to-delta-lake-storage-in-s3/
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Gs4ZsTH19lMxth4BSdwlWjUNR-XhKHicDvBjd2RqNd8/edit#

#### DynamoDB tables

[image]

##### jar files

[image]

#### jar file path provided

[image]

When i run my code i dont see any messages in the dynamodb table
here is code

```
try:
    import os
    import sys

    import pyspark
    from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
    from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
    from pyspark.sql.functions import col, asc, desc
    from pyspark.sql.functions import *
    from delta.tables import *
    from delta.tables import DeltaTable

    print("All modules are loaded .....")

except Exception as e:
    print("Some modules are missing {} ".format(e))


class DeltaLakeHelper(object):
    """
    Delta Lakes Python helper class that aids in basic operations such as inserting, updating, deleting, merging, removing older files and versions, and generating Athena manifest files.
    """

    def __init__(self, delta_lake_path: str):

        self.spark = self.__create_spark_session()
        self.delta_lake_path = delta_lake_path
        self.delta_df = None

    def generate_manifest_files(self):
        """

        Generates Manifest file for Athena

        :return: Bool
        """
        self.delta_df.generate("symlink_format_manifest")
        return True

    def __generate_delta_df(self):
        try:
            if self.delta_df is None:
                self.delta_df = DeltaTable.forPath(self.spark, self.delta_lake_path)
        except Exception as e:
            pass

    def compact_table(self, num_of_files=10):
        """

        Converts smaller parquert files into larger Files

        :param num_of_files: Int
        :return: Bool

        """
        df_read = self.spark.read.format("delta") \
            .load(self.delta_lake_path) \
            .repartition(num_of_files) \
            .write.option("dataChange", "false") \
            .format("delta") \
            .mode("overwrite") \
            .save(self.delta_lake_path)
        return True

    def delete_older_files_versions(self):
        """

        Deletes Older Version and calls vacuum(0)

        :return: Bool
        """
        self.__generate_delta_df()
        self.delta_df.vacuum(0)
        return True

    def insert_overwrite_records_delta_lake(self, spark_df, max_record_per_file='10000'):
        """
        Inserts into Delta Lake

        :param spark_df: Pyspark Dataframe
        :param max_record_per_file: str ie max_record_per_file= "10000"
        :return:Bool
        """
        spark_df.write.format("delta") \
            .mode("overwrite") \
            .option("maxRecordsPerFile", max_record_per_file) \
            .save(self.delta_lake_path)

        return True

    def append_records_delta_lake(self, spark_df, max_record_per_file="10000"):
        """

        Append data into Delta lakes

        :param spark_df: Pyspark Dataframe
        :param max_record_per_file: str ie max_record_per_file= "10000"
        :return: Bool
        """
        spark_df.write.format("delta") \
            .mode('append') \
            .option("maxRecordsPerFile", max_record_per_file) \
            .save(self.delta_lake_path)
        return True

    def update_records_delta_lake(self, condition="", value_to_set={}):
        """

        Set the value on delta lake

        :param condition : Str Example:  condition="emp_id = '3'"
        :param value_to_set: Dict IE  value_to_set={"employee_name": "'THIS WAS UPDATE ON DELTA LAKE'"}
        :return: Bool
        """
        self.__generate_delta_df()
        self.delta_df.update(condition, value_to_set)
        return True

    def upsert_records_delta_lake(self, old_data_key, new_data_key, new_spark_df):
        """

        Find one and update into delta lake
        If records is found it will update if not it will insert into delta lakes
        See Examples on How to use this

        :param old_data_key: Key is nothing but Column on which you want to merge or upsert data into delta lake
        :param new_data_key: Key is nothing but Column on which you want to merge or upsert data into delta lake
        :param new_spark_df: Spark DataFrame
        :return: Bool
        """
        self.__generate_delta_df()
        dfUpdates = new_spark_df

        self.delta_df.alias('oldData') \
            .merge(dfUpdates.alias('newData'), f'oldData.{old_data_key} = newData.{new_data_key}') \
            .whenMatchedUpdateAll() \
            .whenNotMatchedInsertAll() \
            .execute()

        return True

    def delete_records_delta_lake(self, condition=""):
        """

        Set the value on delta lake

        :param condition:Str IE condition="emp_id = '4'"
        :return:Bool
        """
        self.__generate_delta_df()
        self.delta_df.delete(condition)
        return True

    def read_delta_lake(self):
        """

        Reads from Delta lakes

        :return: Spark DF
        """
        df_read = self.spark.read.format("delta").load(self.delta_lake_path)
        return df_read

    def __create_spark_session(self):
        self.spark = SparkSession \
            .builder \
            .config("spark.sql.extensions", "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension") \
            .config("spark.databricks.delta.retentionDurationCheck.enabled", "false") \
            .config("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog") \
            .config("spark.delta.logStore.s3.impl", "io.delta.storage.S3DynamoDBLogStore") \
            .getOrCreate()
        return self.spark


def main():

    try:
        from awsglue.job import Job
        from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
        from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame
        from awsglue.context import GlueContext
    except Exception as e:pass

    helper = DeltaLakeHelper(delta_lake_path="s3a://glue-learn-begineers/deltalake/delta_table")

    args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ["JOB_NAME"])
    spark = helper.spark
    sc = spark.sparkContext
    glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
    job = Job(glueContext)
    job.init(args["JOB_NAME"], args)

    # ====================================================
    """Create Spark Data Frame """
    # ====================================================
    data = impleDataUpd = [
        (1, "this is insert 1 ", "Sales", "RJ", 81000, 30, 23000, 827307999),
        (2, "this is insert 2", "Engineering", "RJ", 79000, 53, 15000, 1627694678),
        (3, "this is insert 3", "Engineering", "RJ", 79000, 53, 15000, 1627694678),
        (4, "this is insert 3", "Engineering", "RJ", 79000, 53, 15000, 1627694678),
    ]
    columns = ["emp_id", "employee_name", "department", "state", "salary", "age", "bonus", "ts"]
    df_write = spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema=columns)
    helper.insert_overwrite_records_delta_lake(spark_df=df_write)

    # ====================================================
    """Appending  """
    # ====================================================
    data = impleDataUpd = [
        (5, "this is append", "Engineering", "RJ", 79000, 53, 15000, 1627694678),
    ]
    columns = ["emp_id", "employee_name", "department", "state", "salary", "age", "bonus", "ts"]
    df_append = spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema=columns)
    helper.append_records_delta_lake(spark_df=df_append)


    # ====================================================
    """READ FROM DELTA LAKE  """
    # ====================================================
    df_read = helper.read_delta_lake()
    print("READ", df_read.show())

    # ====================================================
    """UPDATE DELTA LAKE"""
    # ====================================================
    helper.update_records_delta_lake(condition="emp_id = '3'",
                                     value_to_set={"employee_name": "'THIS WAS UPDATE ON DELTA LAKE'"})

    # ====================================================
    """ DELETE DELTA LAKE"""
    # ====================================================
    helper.delete_records_delta_lake(condition="emp_id = '4'")

    # ====================================================
    """ FIND ONE AND UPDATE OR UPSERT DELTA LAKE """
    # ====================================================
    new_data = [
        (2, "this is update on delta lake ", "Sales", "RJ", 81000, 30, 23000, 827307999),
        (11, "This should be append ", "Engineering", "RJ", 79000, 53, 15000, 1627694678),
    ]

    columns = ["emp_id", "employee_name", "department", "state", "salary", "age", "bonus", "ts"]
    usr_up_df = spark.createDataFrame(data=new_data, schema=columns)

    helper.upsert_records_delta_lake(old_data_key='emp_id',
                                     new_data_key='emp_id',
                                     new_spark_df=usr_up_df)

    # ====================================================
    """ Compaction DELTA Prune Older Version and Create larger Files """
    # ====================================================
    helper.compact_table(num_of_files=2)
    helper.delete_older_files_versions()

    # ====================================================
    """ Create Manifest File for Athena """
    # ====================================================
    helper.generate_manifest_files()

    job.commit()

main()
```

Please advice

Comment: Have you set spark.delta.logStore.s3.impl=io.delta.storage.S3DynamoDBLogStore? and other related settings

Comment: Yes i did that didnt helped  too